# Using freopen to read file

Tags: c, stdin, freopen

I have an assignment where I implement binary search and linear search. The "hard" part is done and both of the those methods are implemented and work.
My professor wants us to test arrays with large number of integers. He gave us a .in file that had input in the style that he wants and I'm trying to use freopen to read the file.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

freopen("input.in", "r", stdin);  // <-----

int n , s;

scanf("%d %d", &n, &s);

int myAr[n];
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    scanf("%d",&myAr[i]);
    i++;
}

int myAr2[s];
int j = 0;
while (j < s) {
    scanf("%d",&myAr2[j]);
    j++;
}
...
```

The file starts out with 2 numbers in one line, number of elements in the list and the number of element that you are looking for in the first list.

then it read a line with all the numbers in list 1 and then the next line reads all the numbers in list 2

I can't get freopen() to work properly and I would like to know if there are any suggestions out there.

sample input.in file:

```
10 2
2 4 6 7 9 10 24 26 29 33
26 35
```

My code would later tell me that 26 is found and 35 was not. My main issue is reading the input file in main instead of manually typing in the terminal. Help please.

Comment: Adding '\n' to the end of the file should help.

Comment: If you can use C++ , look at ifstream,If not, each OS provides file IO function, such as linux open and read... Frankly,I don't understand your mean.

Comment: Why are you fighting with freopen when you could just use file redirection when calling your program. eg a.out < a.in

Comment: As you say your code just can't get last number (35). It's probably due to `scanf` not understands the eof state - it waits for more digits to come in. If you add the newline at the end of the file, then `scanf` should read '35' right.

Comment: what's the problem? which type of error do you have(compile,run time,logical)? and you can't define an array of size n, in run time! you should use "int *myAr = new int[n]" instead.

Comment: Why do you want to use freopen at all? Use fopen, and check return values.

Comment: How do you know `freopen` doesn't work properly?

Comment: Why not use [fscanf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) to do the what you are doing?

Comment: Yeah @rhubarbdog is right! One of my classmates executed read the text file as input when executing in terminal like this: ./executable < input.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read all the integers in the input.in file by simply using `fscanf()`.

Here is my code.

```
int j;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input.in", "r");
while( fscanf(fp,"%d",&j) > 0 )
{
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Output was.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I like how there is another way to do it inside of the file instead of reading the text in terminal. that way i can debug it.